# External column search for DataTables

Tags: search, datatables, server-side

I have a DataTable (1.10.0) running with the help of CodeIgniter. The data is provided by ajax with Datatables library. Everything is running fine.

I would like to insert an input field somewhere on my page to filter/search only one column. I have tried with:

```
$('#customer').on( 'keyup click', function () {
  $('#results').DataTable().search(
    $('#customer').val()
  ).draw();
} );
```

This searches in all columns, and changes the value in the DataTables' own search field. If I add column(), it will not search in the table anymore, although it draws all ajax data again without filter/search.

```
$('#customer').on( 'keyup click', function () {
  $('#results').DataTable().column(0).search(
    $('#customer').val()
  ).draw();
} );
```

My question: What is the proper way to implement external column search/filter on server-side processed data?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using [`column().search()`](http://datatables.net/reference/api/column%28%29.search%28%29) API function correctly.

However with server-side processing, individual column searches are sent in separate request parameters, see [Server-side processing](http://datatables.net/manual/server-side).

For example, if you search the first column with value `John Doe`, your server side script will receive a request with parameter `columns[0][search][value]` set to `John Doe` while global search parameter `search[value]` would be empty.

You need to handle this individual column searches separately on the server-side, either manually or with help of a library.

Comment: Oh, thank you! I see the problem of my solution now. What do you think about this library? https://github.com/zepernick/Codeigniter-DataTables

Comment: NONONO definetly no. Even the demos of the linked solution has errors.